# Printting on dot matrix printer with only Tx, Rx and Ground

Tags: printing, serial-port

My hardware communicate with PC serial port using Tx, Rx and ground lines for sending and receiving data, I wrote a program which can send some text to PC via serial line, now I wanted to alter it in such a way that I should be able to print that data on dot matrix printer which has a serial port.

I am using an Epson LQ 1150 dot matrix printer which has a db25 serial port.  I tried connecting in following manner and sent data over serial line, the printer prints some garbage character and hangs.

```
Tx =  Rx  
Rx  =  Tx  
Ground = Ground
```

I tried searching other posts explaining(db9-M to db25-F) :

```
Receive Data (RxD)  2 = 2  Transmit Data (TxD)  
Transmit Data (TxD) 3 = 3  Receive Data (RxD)   
Data Terminal Ready (DTR) 4 = 6 Data Set Ready (DSR)    
System Ground (SG) 5 = 7 System Ground (SG)     
Data Set Ready (DSR) 6 = 20 Data Terminal Ready (DTR)   
Clear To Send (CTS) 8 = 4 Request To Send (RTS)
```

But I don't have DTR, DSR,and CTS. Is there any way I can make it possible using only 3 lines i.e. Tx, Rr and ground?

Comment: If you get garbage then you probably just guessed the baudrate wrong.  Or parity or datasize.  The handshake signals don't produce garbage.